# how to search data in db

Tags: c#

This code is working fine but when i search `id` like 121452, so it will call all numbers that have "1" or "2" in db. so i want it show only the exact `id` what i search

```
private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\acap\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Student where No_ic = " + boxSearch.Text, con); 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    //dataGridView1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Also, please do not use string concatenation as it is susceptible for SQL Injection and look at parameterized queries.

Comment: sorry, when i search id like 121452, so it will call all number that have "1" or "2" in db. so i want it show only the exact id what i search

Comment: No it won't, not with that query anyways. Please include the output you are now getting with the provided input that is "unexpected". Also do not use string concatenation, use sql parameters instead to avoid a sql injection attack.

Comment: @ashrafibrahim try my answer,if it's help for u please accept it :)

Comment: @SachithMW it doesn't give any output..

Comment: @ashrafibrahim sorry i forgot to set dataset,try it now, its working fine for me :)

Comment: @SachithMW thanks man.. the code is worked for me..

Comment: @ashrafibrahim your welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

**Updated:** (Previously i forgot to bind dataset.)

```
private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   String bResult = boxSearch.Text;
   string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=sacbase;Integrated Security=True"; // add your conncetion string here
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Student where No_ic =@val", connection);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", bResult);
   SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   connection.Open();
   dataadapter.Fill(ds, "student_table");
   connection.Close();
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
   dataGridView1.DataMember = "student_table";
}
```